# Drawing image from array of pixels

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, drawing

I'm trying to write a code that draws a set of pixels from array of indices that point to a color value from another array (essentially palettes). I'm very new to drawing images on screen aside using picture box, so I have no proper experience with stuff like this. According to my research this code should work, but nothing gets drawn on the form. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public string[] colors = new string[] { "#FFFF0000", "#FF00FF00", "#FF0000FF", "#FFFFFF00", "#FFFF00FF", "#FF00FFFF" };
public byte[] pixels = new byte[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 };

public byte scale = 2;

public void PaintPixels()
{
    Graphics g = CreateGraphics();

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for (int p = 0;  p < pixels.Length; p++)
    {
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colors[pixels[p]])))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, scale, scale);
        }

        x += scale;

        if(x > 255)
        {
            y += scale;
            x = 0;
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Width = 256 * scale;
    Height = 240 * scale;

    PaintPixels();
}
```

Comment: Get rid of CreateGraphics.  It's always wrong.  Use the paint event of the control that is supposed to do the painting.

Comment: I could try that. Last time it didn't like the using statement for some reason

Comment: You would have to show *that* code.

Comment: You could just move the code in `PaintPixels()` (starting from `int x = 0;`) in the Paint event of the control that should display the palette. Of course `g` will become `e.Graphics`

Comment: As noted already in the comments, you should be using the `Paint` event or `OnPaint()` method to draw your graphics, not `CreateGraphics()`. See marked duplicates for some details about that.

Answer (score 1):

Just override `Form.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)` like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static readonly string[] colors =
        new string[] { "#FFFF0000", "#FF00FF00", "#FF0000FF", "#FFFFFF00", "#FFFF00FF", "#FF00FFFF" };
    private static readonly byte[] pixels =
        new byte[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 };
    private static readonly byte scale = 10;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        for (int p = 0, x = 0, y = 0; p < pixels.Length; p++, x += scale)
        {
            if (x > 255)
            {
                x = 0;
                y += scale;
            }

            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colors[pixels[p]])))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, scale, scale);
        }
    }
}
```

It gives:

[image]

Comment: Forms don't need to listen to their own events. You could just use the OnPaint override.  Also, don't dispose that graphic object — you didn't create it.

Comment: @ LarsTech, good point! Thanks!